# Animating UICollectionView,but cells disappear

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, animatewithduration

My code like this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^
{
    [ccController.collectionView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 0)];
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    [_selectTabV setHidden:YES];
}];
```

The cells disappear immediately while the animation has not end yet.
why? 
How to let cells disappear follow the collection view animation?
thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Call `[ccController.collectionView layoutIfNeeded];` before your animation block.

Comment: I don't think this works. The issue is that UICollectionView is not properly reusing the cells (or rather, reusing them instantly) because the method used to set the frame/contentoffset/etc is not meant to be called within an animation block. Apple provides their own way to animate those changes (`setContentOffset:amimated:`, etc.) -- but if you use those functions, you can't set your own animation duration, delay, curve, etc.